# Wrong id set when using h:selectOneRadio and f:selectItem

Tags: html, jsf-2, radio-button

This is my code:

```
<h:panelGroup id="deliveryAddress" columns="2">
    <h:selectOneRadio id="deliveryAddressRadioGroup" value="#{mybean.deliveryAddress}" layout="pageDirection" onclick="resetTextField()">
        <f:selectItem id="pickedUp" itemValue="wird abgeholt (WET B4)" itemLabel="#{msg.subscriptionFormFieldDeliveryAddressPickedUp}"/>
        <f:selectItem id="send2OrderingPerson" itemValue="Versand an Bestellenden" itemLabel="#{msg.subscriptionFormFieldDeliveryAddressSend2OrderingPerson}"/>
        <f:selectItem id="send2SubscrOwner" itemValue="Versand an Abonnementsbesitzer" itemLabel="#{msg.subscriptionFormFieldDeliveryAddressSend2SubscrOwner}"/>
        <f:selectItem id="send2SupportGroup" itemValue="Versand an Support-Gruppe" itemLabel="#{msg.subscriptionFormFieldDeliveryAddressSend2SupportGroup}"/>
    </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:panelGroup>
```

From that I expect that the ids of the single buttons are `pickedUp`, `send2OrderingPerson`, `send2SubscrOwner` and `send2SupportGroup`. (or at least detailForm:xxx).

Instead, if I look at the resulting code, I get:

```
<span id="detailForm:deliveryAddress">
    <table id="detailForm:deliveryAddressRadioGroup">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="detailForm:deliveryAddressRadioGroup:0" type="radio" onclick="resetTextField()" value="wird abgeholt (WET B4)" name="detailForm:deliveryAddressRadioGroup">
                    <label for="detailForm:deliveryAddressRadioGroup:0"> will be piched up (WET B4)</label>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="detailForm:deliveryAddressRadioGroup:1" type="radio" onclick="resetTextField()" value="Versand an Bestellenden" name="detailForm:deliveryAddressRadioGroup">
                        <label for="detailForm:deliveryAddressRadioGroup:1"> send to ordering person</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="detailForm:deliveryAddressRadioGroup:2" type="radio" onclick="resetTextField()" value="Versand an Abonnementsbesitzer" name="detailForm:deliveryAddressRadioGroup" checked="checked">
                        <label for="detailForm:deliveryAddressRadioGroup:2"> send to subscription's owner</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                            <input id="detailForm:deliveryAddressRadioGroup:3" type="radio" onclick="resetTextField()" value="Versand an Support-Gruppe" name="detailForm:deliveryAddressRadioGroup">
                            <label for="detailForm:deliveryAddressRadioGroup:3"> send to support group</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</span>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong this is how ids are generated!!

Comment: But if I specify an id name, I expect that the id has that name...

Comment: You're not allowed in HTML to have two elements with the same ID, so what JSF is doing is normal and correct.

Comment: @Boann Which would be the ids with the same name? I defined `pickedUp`, `send2OrderingPerson`, `send2SubscrOwner` and `send2SupportGroup`...

Comment: @Francesco Oh I see. Sorry, yeah. I don't know why it's doing that then.